# How can get this kind of Layout design?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve the UI in the below photo. I am not able to decide which layout should I use. Kindly anyone give some points to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a Linear layout with vertical orientation and within the linear layout(vertical), include linear layouts with horizontal orientation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!--
        online icon
        call icon
    -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--
    Gratuity icon

    -->


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it a card Layout or Grid Layout?

Comment: It is Linear layout